# ImageCache throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: 6, media

I'm trying to use imagecache for the first time. (already installed by someone else. currently not serving any images)

So whenever I try to see an image modified by imagecache I have a 500 internal error. In the drupal's watchdog report log there is just an error without much description:

```
Failed generating an image from imagecache_sample.png using imagecache preset small_analysis.
```

I have no idea why, but in the apache error logs, I can't find anything...

This happens even when I try to display the imagecache sample:

http://www.radicalislam.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/small_analysis/imagecache_sample.png?1344778168=

Answer (score 2):

I've just ran into this issue and i solved it by enabling the `ImageAPI GD2` module and disabling the `ImageAPI ImageMagick` module.

There's also a number of things to check: presence of the GD library in system and in PHP config, enough PHP memory to parse the images, valid file system configuration and permissions, etc.